# Emulating transparency to avoid discrepancies among pdf viewers/printers - TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, printing, transparency

I previously asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430801/tikz-path-fading-doesnt-print) about why my transparent fades weren't showing up or printing and it seems that the transparency feature in pdfs isn't uniformly supported.

So my new question is this: is there a way to draw something that gives the same visual effect as transparency without using that feature?

I'll use the same MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill [blue!80!black, path fading=east] (0,0) --++ (90:0.3) --++ (0:6) --++ (-90:0.3) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/graphics-def/issues/16

Comment: You mean implementing transparency yourself?

Comment: @percusse I mean getting an output that looks like my transparent example, but without using features which aren't universally displayed/printed. "looks like" being the important phrase.

Comment: As I said, first start by flattening your PDF, then try another viewer, then try another printer driver, then try another printer and if all fails then try Adobe InDesign like software. If all fails then you can think what else left to do. You are starting from the bottom. If you really need asap, place a for loop and stack 250 rectangles horizontally with color changing.

Comment: Or 256 rectangles since RGB model ranges from 0 to 255.